# New Relic for ASP .NET 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-core, newrelic

I am trying to configure new relic for my ASP .NET website monitoring. Mine is ASP.NET 5 application. I am unable to add new relic packages to my application.
I am getting reference errors. Can any one help how to configure New Relic for ASP .NET 5 application. Am I missing something..?

Comment: Can you please a little more details? How do you add the packages? What errors do you get? What package sources do you have?

Comment: Tried to add the latest version of package NewRelic.Agent.Api. Unable to resolve and add the references.   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/, https://www.myget.org/F/fabrikam-packs/api/v2 are the three package sources. When I host the site without adding the package, NewRelic status monitor shows no data sent.

Comment: Please share the `project.json` file or at least some more details

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "NewRelic.Agent.Api": "5.6.53"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "webroot": "wwwroot"
}.

Comment: Mostly sure the NewRelic package doesn't support CoreCLR (dnxcore50). Try removing `dnxcore50` from `project .json`

Comment: I tried removing dnxcore50. Still not working. Tried the same steps for a web application with .net framework 4.5. It is working fine.

Comment: Can you please share more details? It's not clear what's not working. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Will newrelic packages support ASP .NET 5.? I am unable to add packages.?Getting errors under references section..Getting the following error.  Restore failed
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\<UserFolder>\.dnx\packages\NewRelic.Agent.Api\5.6.53.0\NewRelic.Agent.Api.5.6.53.0.nupkg.sha512'.

Comment: Will newrelic packages support ASP .NET 5.? I am unable to add packages.?Getting the following error.  Restore failed
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\<UserFolder>\.dnx\packages\NewRelic.Agent.Api\5.6.53.0\NewRelic.Agent.Api.5.6.53.0.nupkg.sha512'. The NewRelic documentation says, for applications hosted in IIS, we need to install NewRelicDotNet Agent and nothing else. I installed the agent, but not getting any data. For applications with .NET framework 4.5, I can install the package and I am getting data.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the official NewRelic request for ASPNet Core support answer [here](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/asp-net-5-vnext/12589/16). Scroll down to the bottom for the product team estimated deliver time schedule.